# Flex works in chrome but not in IE

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

[image: Background Red is not growing completely as per screen size]

the html structure of the code is as shown below. Now I have given background:red to timeline className ( to check if the child gets shrink or grow when minimizing and maximizing the window size). 
timeline is parent for cluster, eventitem, today, todatedate.

When I try to minimize and maximize by rescaling the window size, in chrome it works well but in IE it is broken.

I am not sure where i am going wrong. Seems timeline is not flex grow:1.

[image: Works well in chrome]
code structure

```
<div class="data">
    <div class="dataselect__main "> 
        <div class="dataselect__content" >
        <div class="logic_scrollbararea">
            <div class="timeline">
                ::before
                <div class="data__moredata--buttoncontainer">
                    <div class="data__moredata--button">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline__item__cluster" ></div>
                <div class="timeline__item__eventItem" ></div>
                <div class="timeline__item__todayItem "></div>
                <div class="timeline__item__todaydateItem "></div>
                <div class="timeline__nodataavailable" ></div>
                ::after
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.dataselect__main{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:flex;
    flex:1;
}
.dataselect__content{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex:1;
    min-height:0;
    min-width:0;
}
.logic_scrollbararea{
    display: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
}
.timeline {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 3.125rem;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    background:red;
 }
.timeline:before {
    content: "";
    height: 0.375rem;
    border-radius: 0.3125rem;
    border: 0.125rem solid #1f1f1f;
    background-color: #2d6483;
    display: block;
    top: 3.125rem;
    left: 0;
    right: 0.25rem;
    margin-top: 0.4375rem;
}
.timeline:after {
    content: "";
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    border: 0.125rem solid #1f1f1f;
    background: #389dd5;
    top: 3.125rem;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 0.25rem;
    width: 0.75rem;
    height: 0.75rem;
}
```

Comment: Burn ie ... BURN IT!!!!
https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: @ScottChambers yes. i checked in this, and IE 11 supports flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `min-width: 100%` use `width:100%` on timeline. So your time line code will be:

```
.logic_scrollbararea {
    width: 100%;
}

.timeline {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 3.125rem;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Flex Support IE 11, So Output in IE

[image]

Comment: i tried that but the width remains the same like i showed before . may be the parent div of timeline blocking the width or so.

Comment: I also tried t test the issue with IE 11 and looks like using width instead of min-width can solve the issue. Can you please try to just make with the above sample to see the output? If it works than you can try to implement in your original code.

Comment: i tried this as well didnt work. here increased the width to 200% to see if it really takes the css and it did change..seems width:100% is what it has taken..

Comment: timeline__item__cluster has some contents. when contents are shrinked everything looks good. when the contents are expanded horizontally, the content cluster increased and due to specified width , scroll bar appears but the "timeline" itself not growing.

Comment: Looks like the example you provided in the original post and the image you posted above is not getting matched. Please try to check and verify that your code able to produce the issue in a similar way as your image shows. It can help us to understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: i shall create a test demo using test application and will check if IE is real cause or some other issue in code.

Comment: You can also try to share that demo here. We will also try to test it on our side to see the result. It can help to narrow down the issue and we can try to provide further suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 support : flex

IE 10 : only flexbox

There is syntax for old browsers:

```
  .page-wrap {
      display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
      display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
      display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
      display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
      display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

 }
```

Comment: i tried this.instead of display flex, i gave -ms-flexbox. no working as expected. className timeline seems to have width of window size and when i shrink or grow the window size, the timeline is not growing or shrinking.